# samplecsipsimple sip

Tags: sip, pjsip

I am looking over csipsimple app - uses sip calls, registers. I also found samplecsipsimple that registers a sip client to the a sip server using the csipsimple as a library. I would like how to create an outbound call and imbound call on wifi using csipsimple as a library?

Need some help.
Appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since CSipSimple uses a wrapper for pjsua, you should take a look at [simple-pjsua](http://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/page__pjsip__sample__simple__pjsuaua__c.htm) program. And since there is no callback mechanism in Java, you wont be able to use the callbacks (such as on_call_state). so what you need to do is to extend the **Callback** class and override **all** of it's methods. Look in the code how it is done.